# Custom component attribute types

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I was wondering if i can pass other types of arguments than `int, String` to custom components explained [here](https://angulardart.org/tutorial/05-ch03-component.html).
My problem is that i want to make a component and i want to pass data of type `List`, especially `List<Map<String, String>>` to the component itself. How can i achive this functionality? In other words, how can i pass other arguments to a component in angulardart than int or String?

My related code looks like this:

```dart
@NgComponent(
...
)
class MyComponent {
 List<Map<String, String>> myList;
 ...
 @NgAttr('myAttr')
 set setMyAttribute(List<Map<String, String>> myList) {
  this.myList = myList;
 }
 ...
}
```

---

Where i use the component:

```dart
<div>
...
<mycomponent myAttr="ctrl.returnsAListOfMaps"></mycomponent>
...
</div>
```

Any idea? Is it possible?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `@NgAttr` the literal value of the attribute is assigned to the fild.
With `@NgOneWay`, `@NgTwoWay`, `@NgOneWayOneTime` the attribute value is evaluated and the result gets assigned.
`@NgCallback` is for assigning callback functions.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use many kind of types with component attributes (map, list and even object/class).

Here you can find a couple of examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21961449/2777805